# Is there a way to change a dimension of a mesh by a specific percent?

Tags: mesh, objects, edit-mode, transforms

I'm working with imported terrain meshes and for some of these meshes I would like to change the vertical (Z) dimension by a specific percent. Is there a way to do this?

For example, I import a terrain into Blender that by default has a 4x vertical exaggeration. Once in Blender, I would like to change its scale so that Z=25% while X & Y remain at 100%. I could eyeball it, but entering numerical values would be faster. Thanks.

Blender 2.93.5 Windows 10

Comment: In Edit mode, select your mesh and press S+Z+0.25?

Answer (score 2):

The scale command takes both an axis and a numerical argument.

For your example, <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> would scale the *selection* to 25% of its size only on the Z axis.

The axis designation is optional.  If you use <kbd>Shift</kbd> before the axis letter it will scale on the other two axis.  I.E. <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> will scale on X and Y but not Z.

If you leave the axis out it scales on all three axis.

If you don't specify a number it scales only on the selected axes, but using left-mouse drag.

If you scale in object mode, be sure to apply the scale.

Comment: Works great moonboots. Thanks! :)